# How do I use Mathematica to extract data points from DICOM images?

Tags: export, image-processing, education

I have few DICOM images whose data points I would like to extract and probably export (which would really be excellent) to an excel file.

Comment: From the documentation: Import and Export fully support DICOM files conforming to Section PS 3.10 of the DICOM standard.

Comment: Which part is giving you problems? What have you already tried? Do you have an example image?